# Try to put string that call from graph API to database sq-lite but that value in database is null

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Me and my team have been doing this for many days but still can't figure it out what I'm trying to do is that use Graph API Facebook to call for user ID (Already done that and check that it's work by use Log) and take that value in to sq-lite database but when I check that value it's NULL. Sorry for bad English skill. Here's some of the code

```
String userId, userName; //Global values
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            data = new Data(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = data.getWritableDatabase();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                                GraphResponse response) {

                            userId = object.optString("id");
                            Log.d("id", userId); 
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Information (userId) VALUES ('" + userId +"');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('First exercise', 'Exercise', '10');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Stronger', 'Exercise', '50');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Body builder', 'Exercise', '100');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('First check-in', 'Check-in', '1');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Go around', 'Check-in', '10');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Become tourist', 'Check-in', '50');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Traveller', 'Check-in','100');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Wait! Is this the same place?', 'Check-in', '1');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('First time here', 'Todo', '1');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('So busy', 'Todo', '10');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Business man', 'Todo', '50');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('What todo first', 'Todo', '100');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('First times Saving', 'Saving', '1');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Money kids style', 'Saving', '10');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Way to rich', 'Saving', '200');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Rich boy', 'Saving', '2000');");
            db.close();
            data.close();
            loginState();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to write in db userId value, when it's not already initialized. GraphRequest.newMeRequest executes in other thread and you need to wait for  onCompleted to get called and then write to db.

```
  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {

                        userId = object.optString("id");
                        Log.d("id", userId); 
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Information (userId) VALUES ('" + userId +"');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('First exercise', 'Exercise', '10');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Stronger', 'Exercise', '50');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Body builder', 'Exercise', '100');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('First check-in', 'Check-in', '1');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Go around', 'Check-in', '10');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Become tourist', 'Check-in', '50');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Traveller', 'Check-in','100');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Wait! Is this the same place?', 'Check-in', '1');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('First time here', 'Todo', '1');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('So busy', 'Todo', '10');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Business man', 'Todo', '50');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('What todo first', 'Todo', '100');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('First times Saving', 'Saving', '1');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Money kids style', 'Saving', '10');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Way to rich', 'Saving', '200');");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Achievement (AName, AType, AScore) VALUES ('Rich boy', 'Saving', '2000');");
        db.close();
        data.close();
        loginState();
                    }
                });
        request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Very Thank you. When I show my answer to my team one of my team realize that Graph API is asynchronous it didn't finish yet like you said. And again very thank you for your answer. You save my day